# ML sequence classification

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a problem for classifying a specific type of Rock (rock_type) in a log consisting of 8 columns. The logs are a sequence with one column being depth.

E.g.

```
depth    f_1   f_2   ...   f_n       rock_type
 0       0.4   0.3         14.5        0 
1.3      0.2   0.1         13.8        0
2.4      0.8   0.3         9.7         1
3.2      1.4   0.3         12.5        1
4.9      1.8   2.6         15.2        1
```

I have a training set as listed above with labels at each point.

The problem is that the rock types generally occur in batches/chunks. Meaning that you will have the same rocktype multiple times after each other (not just at one depth point).

The approach I have taken so far is using normal ML classification models (RF/XGBoost) which gives a fair performance, but the model doesn't take into account that this is a time series problem as I see it - because if point t-1 is rock_type 0, it is likely that the next point (t) is rock_type 0 as well).  And I have therefore thought of using LSTM (Keras/tensorflow) or similar models for this.

The test set I have is a continuous sequence where I want to divide certain parts of the sequence into different types of rocks. (e.g. depth from 300-450 m is rock 0, depth from 700-780 is rock 1 etc).

I have also though of using CNN for this. Identifying parts of the sequence as specific rock types.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSTM should work, but might be overkill. LSTM works amazing when the order matters a lot (think letters in a word). In your problem you might care more about the distribution of rock types rather than what was the exact sequence of rock types.

So What I would try is to build buckets (previous x meters) and encode the rock type distribution (say .45 of type 0, .15 type 1 and .40 type 2 or something like that). This has the advantage that it's going to be faster to train as well and likely more easy to explain/understand. You need to try different values for x or how many different buckets you keep.

You should also include a dropout layer on the input to make sure your model generalizes correctly. The danger is that the model looks only on the previous buckets and ignores the other signals (bagging will not help).

Comment: Thank you. This is a very interesting approach.

Often times, between rock types, there are transitions from one rock type to the other. I.e. there can be a few points in sequence that will tell you that now we are transitioning from rock type 0 to 1. And therefore the next rock type is 1. So the transitions often times have soft boundaries, compared to hard/rigid boundaries if that makes sense.

Any input on this?

Comment: It should work with both soft and hard boundaries, but the bucket size should be appropriate (you need to try various values). You can also try to apply a decay to the values that go into the bucket (alpha ^ delta_depth, for some alpha in [0, 1] ). This will put more weight on the closest samples. You need to try various combinations and see what works best.

Comment: Interesting idea for feature engineering you're drawing here. I will try this approach. I guess there is no right answer to this question, but I will accept yours. Thank you.